# Creating custom iterators in Python to search for sublists within large datasets

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, search, generator

I'm learning/experimenting with iterators/generators in Python to create a fast search function that can search a large data set for a subset from front to back and back to front simultaneously. I've created a Search Class that I intend to thread its instances so they perform a search in parallel. I am trying to understand the usefulness of generators and want to know if this is a situation where they are in fact useful. The way I have it set up, the dataset must still be loaded into memory. Is there a way to do this where the entire dataset doesn't have to be stored in a variable. Any guidance on my approach to this idea would be greatly appreciated!

```
class Search:

    def __init__(self, dataset):
        self.data = dataset
        self.index = 0
        self.end = len(dataset) - 1

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.index <= self.end:
            yield self.index
            self.index += 1

    def __reversed__(self):
        i = self.end
        while i >= self.index:
            yield i
            i -= 1

    def search(self, subset, reverse=False):
        switch = (iter(self), reversed(self)) 
        for index in switch[reverse]:
            if self.data[index] != subset[0]:
                continue 
        else:
            sub = slice(index, index + len(subset))
            if self.data[sub] == subset:
                result = index 
                break
            else:
                result = 'Not Found!'
    return result


    x = Search(large_data)

    #thread_1:

    x.search(sublist)

    #thread_2:

    x.search(sublist, reverse=True)
```

Comment: In general, you can't reverse an arbitrary generator (or even compute its length), unless there is some *a priori* knowledge about how the sequence is generated. (For instance, you could reverse a `range` object in constant space, because you know it's just counting backwards from a fixed end-point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you need iteration in the dataset loading function. And here it depends, where does the data come from. For files and databases you will find easy solutions in the documentation. If you are using some web API, you may use pagination.